# CircleCI publish the artifacts to a cloud server?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, circleci

I need to publish the build artifacts (e.g. `.apk` files) to a Cloud Server. Could someone please help me to do the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from CircleCI forum.
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/publish-the-artifacts-to-a-cloud-server/4010/3

**ghr**  https://github.com/tcnksm/ghr is a simple tool to create GitHub Release and upload artifacts by only one command. ghr uploads multiple artifacts in parallel.

```
- ghr -t $GITHUB_TOKEN -u $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME -r $CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME v1.0.$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/ || true
```

Please note to mention CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS in the environment variables.

Comment: Is there any way to include artifacts in build email ?